# How to store a value in localStorage by using Backbone.LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

If I try the following code:

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection(); 

c.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("items");  

c.add({title: 'exemple'});

c.toJSON(); // [object]
```

If I try to see the `localStorage.items` I can not see anything.

How should I store the data in localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

In order to save your collection in localStorage you need to `create a new instance of a model within a collection`.

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection(); 

c.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("items");  

c.create({title: 'exemple'});

c.toJSON(); // [object]

localStorage.items; // will be defined
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do? Backbones localStorage adapter is for saving models to localStorage instead of a REST service. If you try to store some additional value in localStorage you can still use `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")`

Comment: I am trying to store a backbone.collection in my localStorage.